# Validating if the Ext.grid.panel is empty

Tags: extjs4.1

I am trying to create a grid panel, that should highlight the grid in red, (as it happens when the validations fail on other components,) when the grid is empty. Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: What do you want highlighted in red? The rows? The border? When can the grid be empty? Only on load? When the store changes?

Comment: The border should be highlighted. On load & also when the store changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the most basic level you can add this css:

```
.grid-highlight {
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

And upon load (or datachanged) events check if the store is empty and then do either:

```
iGrid.addCls( '.grid-highlight' );
iGrid.removeCls( '.grid-highlight' );
```